# unable to import libraries to python 3.6 ,libraries installed in python 2.7

Tags: python, python-3.x, import

My machine runs on Windows 10, I have installed recently python 3.6 along with my previous python 2.7, unable to import libraries in python 3.6.

Comment: the libraries are not reusable between different python versions. you will want to reinstall those libraries again for python 3.6. i.e. `python3 -m pip install SomePackage` https://docs.python.org/3/installing/index.html#basic-usage

Answer (score 0):

You can reinstall all libraries installed by saving list of them:

`python -m pip freeze > libraries.txt`

(please notice `python` is Python 2.7 here)

Next you should install all of them with Python 3:

`python3 - pip install -r libraries.txt`

But not all old libraries are compatible with new version of Python!

Comment: You should locate `python3` and use full path or add it to `PATH` environment variable. Try type `where python3` to find full path.